# Scrolling of iOS UITableView out of view visual errors

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

NOOB. I have a lock button to lock values into a table cell in a UITableView. On click, the underlying model is updated (isLocked boolean) and I switch the image to a closed lock from an open lock and change the background color.

All works fine. Except when scrolling a long list of cells out of the view and back in. I get incorrect cells displaying or sometimes losing the new bg color and graphic.

I'm sure I'm needing to update the UITableView at some point? I just don't know how or when. Have been trying tableView.reloadData() and .reloadRows(at: ... in the locking function without luck.

some code here...
Table View setup

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   // do a whole lot of stuff and then set the lock button tag
   cell.lockButton.tag = indexPath.row

   // Return cell for display
   return cell
}
```

lock function

```
func slideLockFunc(sender: UIButton, peopleData: inout [PersonData], peopleTableView: UITableView) {

// when lock is clicked change the peopleData lock value to locked and the graphic to locked
if let cell: PersonTableCell = ((peopleTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:sender.tag, section: 0))) as? PersonTableCell) {

    if peopleData[sender.tag].isLocked == false {
        peopleData[sender.tag].isLocked = true
        cell.lockButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon-locked"), for: .normal)
        cell.cellBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.995, green: 0.924, blue: 0.924, alpha: 1)
    }
    else {
        peopleData[sender.tag].isLocked = false
        cell.lockButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "unlock"), for: .normal)
        cell.cellBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

}
```

Any help? THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never make cell's property changes outside the `cellForRowAt` you need to just change your data source array and then need to reload the `tableView`'s row. Also instead of working with `tag` try to get `indexPath` using `convert(_:to:)` to get location of tapped and the `indexPathForRow(at:)` with that location to get `indexPath` of that cell's.

```
func slideLockFunc(sender: UIButton, peopleData: inout [PersonData], peopleTableView: UITableView) {
    let point = sender.superview?.convert(sender.center, to: peopleTableView) ?? CGPoint.zero
    if let indexPath = peopleTableView.indexPathForRow(at: point) {        
        peopleData[indexPath.row].isLocked = !peopleData[indexPath.row].isLocked 
        peopleTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Now with your `lockButton` either in interface builder or in `awakeFromNib` of cell set this both image with `default/normal` and `selected` state of button so you don't need to change it every time need to simply select and deselect the button.

```
class PersonTableCell: UITableViewCell {

     @IBOutlet var lockButton: UIButton!

     override func awakeFromNib() {
         lockButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "unlock"), for: .normal)
         lockButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon-locked"), for: .selected)
     }
}
```

Now in `cellForRowAt` method you just need to check for `isLocked` property of your custom object.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier") as! PersonTableCell

    //Now use isLocked property to change the lockButton state
    cell.lockButton.isSelected = peopleData[indexPath.row].isLocked
    cell.cellBackground.backgroundColor = peopleData[indexPath.row].isLocked ? UIColor(red: 0.995, green: 0.924, blue: 0.924, alpha: 1) : UIColor.white
    //your other code
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nirav. Great pointers thanks. Couple things...
I tried using UISwitch but it doesn't have SetImage and on and off image are deprecated to used UIButton.

Comment: @Sean Welcome mate :) Don't get you **I tried using UISwitch but it doesn't have SetImage and on and off image are deprecated to used UIButton** ? If you have any query please edit your question with your current issue that you are facing

Comment: Also I have a bug when using your suggestions where indexPath gets 4294967295 indices when point is set sometimes. (I think it's when switching back to normal) And the function won't work. 
When indexpath is then set on the next line it gets its' 2 indices properly. Any tips?

Comment: @Sean Don't getting you will you please edit your question with your current code that you are using also from where you are calling this method `slideLockFunc(sender:peopleData:peopleTableView:)` ?

Comment: Sorry. Figured it out. Thanks! (needed to remove sender.tag and change switch to button in new code)

Comment: @Sean Welcome mate, glad you made it :)

Answer (score 0):

That happens because dealing with graphics such as images and colors is computationally expensive and also because the way that `UITableView` works by reusing cells.

One way to solve that is by using a cache. For example, if I want to set the background color for the cell, I can do the following:

```
let colorCache = NSCache<NSString, UIColor>()
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // ...

    backgroundColorString: String? = ""

    setupCellBackgroundColor(){
        backgroundColorString = colorString

        backgroundColor = nil

        if let colorFromCache = colorCache.object(forKey: colorString as NSString){
            backgroundColor = colorFromCache
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            // This is my own logic to convert the colorString into a color, you can implement yours
            let colorToCache = FilterParser.getColor(of: colorString)

            if self.backgroundColorString == colorString {
                self.backgroundColor = colorToCache
            }

            colorCache.setObject(colorToCache, forKey: colorString as NSString)
        })
    }

}
```

You can also do the same for the images:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var imageNameString: String? = ""

    // ...

    setupButtonImage(){
        imageNameString = imageString

        lockButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)

        if let imageFromCache = Cache.object(forKey: imageString as NSString){
            lockButton.setImage(imageFromCache, for: .normal)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            let imageToCache = UIImage(named: "imageString")

            if self.imageNameString == imageString {
                lockButton.setImage(imageToCache, for: .normal)
            }

            imageCache.setObject(imageToCache, forKey: imageString as NSString)
        })
    }

}
```

Basically what I'm doing is caching colors and images, so I only will create once and after that I retrieve from the cache, this is going to use more memory, but it will give me a better performance when working with table or collection views.

There are many libraries that can help you to manage a cache, for images that I retrieve from the internet, I like to use [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage).